# Correctly use ifdef to do custom debugging

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to print message only if it's a debug version. So I wrote the following code:

```
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
#define dbg_printf fprintf
#else
#define dbg_printf
#endif

dbg_printf(stderr, "item: %s\n", config[i]);
```

And when MY_DEBUG is not defined I got the following message:

```
main.c:xxx:xxx: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
             dbg_printf(stderr, "item: %s\n", config[i]);
```

I'm trying to avoid that message, but should I add `-Wunused-value` to CFLAGS? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your macro, when expanding to nothing, leaves behind the argument list which becomes a stranded comma-expression. The usual solution is to match and forward the argument list within the macro, and replace it all with a noop statement when disabled.

```
#ifdef MY_DEBUG
#define dbg_printf(...) fprintf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define dbg_printf(...) (0)
#endif
```

Comment: I believe it should be sufficient just to do `#define dbg_printf(...)` too, without the null statement. The macro call then gets replaced with `;`.

Comment: @Lundin this just enables using the `dbg_printf` call as an expression as `fprintf` could be. Edit: yup, I had absent-mindedly put a void-expression instead. Whoops.

Comment: @pmg that is what my brain intended to do before it delegated to my fingers. Thanks!

Comment: @pmg It prevents against a couple of weird silent typos, such as `dbg_printf().0`. Paranoid but harmless :shrug: